# I keep getting java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to read file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android development and Kotlin, so as a project, I want to make a currency converter in Android Studio. To do this, I have saved a currency list file in my assets folder and I want to read the file and put the contents into spinners. Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.*

class currency_converter : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var currency_1: Spinner
    lateinit var currency_2: Spinner

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency_converter)


        val inputStream: InputStream = File("currency_list.txt").inputStream()
        val currency_list = mutableListOf<String>()

        inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { currency_list.add(it) } }

        currency_1 = findViewById(R.id.currency_1) as Spinner
        currency_2 = findViewById(R.id.currency_2) as Spinner

        currency_1.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currency_list)
        currency_2.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currency_list)

    }
}
```

When I run the full emulator through my phone, it opens up, but when I click on the currnecy converter, it crashes and I get the error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: currency_list.txt (No such file or directory)

Any help as to what I could be doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting your file?

Comment: In the assets folder. Between the Java folder and the res folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `assets` to open the file:

```
val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open("currency_list.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

For reading from a file, make sure your file is within your assets folder. You will need to create this. It'll be next to your java and res folder.

```
assets/my_file.json
java/...
res/...
```

Now, I would also suggest using json for any files you're trying to read like this. It'll make it way faster, and it'll also make it very easy for you.

You'll have a file that looks something like this. Where you have an array (square brackets ) of Objects ( curly brackets ). And then you can create your Objects just like you have them setup in your code.

```
{
    "currencies": [
        {
            "name": "USD",
            "value": 1.0
        },
        {
            "name": "CAD",
            "value": 0.65
        }, 
        {
            "name": "AUS",
            "value": 1.22
        }

        // any more currencies
    ]

    // anything else you want to store
}
```

Then you can create a Class for your Currency.

```
data class Currency( val name: String, val value: Float )
```

Notice how the names are the same, and using Gson ( Google's Json reader ), it'll bind everything for you.

And let's create another Class that's just the file structure to make it even easier.

```
data class CurrencyFile( currencies: List<Currency> )
```

Now to open and read the file.

```
fun getCurrencyFile(context: Context) : CurrencyFile {
        val stream = context.assets.open("my_file.json")

        val size = stream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)

        stream.read(buffer)
        stream.close()

        return fromJson(String(buffer), CurrencyFile::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access assets directly from application:

```
 val currencies = "currency_list.txt" 
val currenciesString = application.assets.open(currencies).bufferedReader().use{ it.readText() }
```